# Load data from dictionary to csv

Tags: python, csv, dictionary, text

I have a dictionary in this format:

```
data_dict = {'a' : [1,2,3], 'b' : [[4,5],[6,7],[8,9]]}
```

What I would like to do is parse data from dictionary to csv file in a column 'format'. So key would be a title, and values goes afterwards, so the output should look like:

```
a    b
1    [4,5]
2    [6,7]
3    [8,9]
```

I have tried to use `csv.DictWriter` or `csv.writer` but nothing have worked out for me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [`zip`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions#zip) to aggregates elements from multiple iterables:

```
>>> rows = zip([1,2,3], [[4,5],[6,7],[8,9]])
>>> for row in rows:
...     print(row)
...
(1, [4, 5])
(2, [6, 7])
(3, [8, 9])
```

---

```
import csv
import sys

data_dict = {'a' : [1,2,3], 'b' : [[4,5],[6,7],[8,9]]}    
keys = sorted(data_dict)  # to get ordered keys
values = [data_dict[key] for key in keys]

writer = csv.writer(sys.stdout, delimiter='\t')  # Replace `sys.stdout` as you need
writer.writerow(keys)
for row in zip(*values):
    writer.writerow(row)
```